# Computing the convex hull of several polyhedra

Tags: cg.comp-geom, optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $K_1,..., K_m$ be a set of $m$ polyhedra, with $K_i\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$, for all $i\in [m]$, and each is described by a set of $poly(n)$ linear inequalities.
How easy is it to compute an efficient description (half-space representation, or vertex representation) of the convex hull:
$$
conv(K_1,...,K_n).
$$
Is there an algorithm running in time $poly(n)$,  $poly(n,m)$ ?

Similarly, given membership oracles to $K_1,...,K_n$ can one determine in polynomial time, w.r.t. these oracles, whether a point $x$ belongs to $conv(K_1,...,K_n)$?

Comment: This is impossible since the number of facets of the convex hull can be as large as (roughly) $m^{n/2}$, even if each $K_i$ is a single point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: The convex hull might have exponentially many vertices and exponentially many faces.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Higher_dimensions

Comment: There is an oracle that given a point $x$ determines whether $x$ belongs to the convex hull of $K_1,\dots, K_n$ in polynomial-time. If $x$ is not in the convex hull, the oracle finds a separating hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks Yury.  I have modified the question accordingly, since essentially this is what I was looking for.  Can I kindly ask that you supply some reference for the claim you mentioned?

Comment: @LiorEldar: We construct a separation oracle that determines whether $\hat x$ is in the convex null or not. Here is how the oracle works. We look for a separating hyperplane of the form $c^T x \geq c_0$ that separates $\hat x$ with each of $K_i$. We write a linear program with variables $c = (c_1,\dots, c_d)^T$ and $c_0$. We write an LP condition that $c^T\hat x \geq c_0$ and that each $K_i$ lies on the other side of the hyperplane. The latter condition for $K_i$ means that $(c, c_0')$ is a convex combination of face hyperplanes of $K_i$ and $c_0' \leq c_0$.

Comment: @Yury I think that counts as an answer.

Comment: @Yury: I don't see how the latter condition is formulated as an LP?   For each $K_i$ you would need the following condition: that any point $y$ for which all linear constraints of $K_i$ hold, also has $c^T y< c_0$, no?.  Also, I certainly agree that this is an answer.

Comment: @Yury: The polyhedra $K_i$ are given by membership oracles, and so we don't know (or cannot extract) an inequality description of $K_i$ that is needed for your formulation.

Comment: @YoshioOkamoto: I was answering the question Lior asked me. See the original statement of the question and the discussion above (note that the question was edited several times). If sets $K_i$ are given by oracles, then we can still construct a membership oracle for the convex hull of $K_i$ but the oracle is a bit more complicated.